# TypeError running RNN tutorial from Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Simply trying to run the unmodified [RNN Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/) tutorial on a Centos 7 machine.  I have `yum update`d the machine.  Installed python3.6, pulled the tutorial from github, downloaded and untarred the sample data.  Other tutorials run.  Then I run:

```
python3.6 ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/
```

Which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 374, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 334, in main
    train_input = PTBInput(config=config, data=train_data, name="TrainInput")
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 94, in __init__
    data, batch_size, num_steps, name=name)
  File "/root/tensorflow/models/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py", line 117, in ptb_producer
    [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps])
TypeError: strided_slice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strides'
```

As a total NOOB, I am completely stuck!  Can anyone help?

Comment: I got the RNN to work, but only managed to do so with either Python 3.6 and tf version 1.0.0-rc1, or with python 3.5. Could you tell the version of TF you are using ?  I advise you to use conda environments, to switch more easily between versions

Comment: Tensorflow is 0.12.1  -  I used the 'pip' install; how do I upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment on the question above, I installed `TensorFlow 1.0.0rc1`.   I used `pip3.6`, but as I was on Centos, the [OS Setup guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup) doesn't address it, so I had to try each download:

```
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# pip3.6 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# pip3.6 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# pip3.6 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp33-cp33m-linux_x86_64.whl
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# pip3.6 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp33-cp33m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# pip3.6 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
    Collecting tensorflow==1.0.0rc1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl (43.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 43.5MB 28kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf>=3.1.0 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.11.0 in /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: packaging>=16.8 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==1.0.0rc1)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow 0.12.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-0.12.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-0.12.1
Successfully installed tensorflow-1.0.0rc1
```

So the correct URL for `RHEL/Centos` is: `tensorflow-1.0.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`.  Verify your upgrade by running:

```
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# python3.6 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.0.0-rc1
```

Now run the tutorial again, the `TypeError` is gone, but is replaced by an `AttributeError`:

```
(tensorflow) [tensorflow]# python3.6 ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 149, in __init__
     output = tf.reshape(tf.concat_v2(outputs, 1), [-1, size])
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'concat_v2'
```

Turns out that TWO tensorflow APIs changed:

1. `concat_v2` goes away and is replaced simply by: `concat`
2. Likewise, `scalar_summary` has been renamed to: `summary.scalar`.  There are 3 such references in ptb_word_lm.py

Edit `ptb_word_lm.py` to make both of the changes above AND the tutorial should now run correctly for you!